# Interchange supremum and expectation

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $B_n:=\{f\in L^\infty_+\mid f\le n \}$, where we consider $L^\infty$ with the weak$^*$ topology. I have the following sets

$$D(z):=\{h\in L^0_+(\mathcal{F}_T)\mid h\le Z_T \mbox{ for a }Z\in Z(z)\}$$
where $Z(z)$ is the set of positive (RCLL) supermartingales on $[0,T]$ with $E[Z_0]\le z$. Moreover $U$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}$, strictly increasing, strictly concave and $C^1$. For a $h\in D(z)$ I want to prove

$$\sup_{f\in B_n} E[U(f)-hf]=E[\sup_{f\in B_n}\{U(f)-fh\}]$$

One direction is clear: $E[U(f)-hf]\le E[\sup_{f\in B_n}\{U(f)-fh\}]$, hence

$$\sup_{f\in B_n} E[U(f)-hf]\le E[\sup_{f\in B_n}\{U(f)-fh\}]$$

the inequality $"\ge "$ is bothering me. How can I tackle this problem? I know that the equality is true. Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you remind me what you mean by $L^0_+$.

Comment: @Tim with $L_+^0$ we denote the space of measurable real valued function, which are positive.

Comment: OK,  But I'm struggling with the idea that $h\leq Z_T$ for some $Z\in Z(z)$.  $Z_T$  is a random variable. How can a deterministic function be less than a random variable?

Comment: @Tim it is a map from $\Omega$ into the reals. hence it is a r.v. with respect to $\mathcal{F}_T$

Comment: Gotcha.  I was interpreting your $L^p$ spaces as sets of maps $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: @ math:  I'm still trying to work out your notation.  I think $h:\Omega\to\mathbb R^+$ is a fixed random variable with $E(h)\leq z$, $B_n$ is a set of random variables $\Omega\to[0,n]$ and $U:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is fixed.  If so I'll post an answer.

Comment: @Tim yes and in fact the domain of $U$ is the positive real line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $U:\mathbb R^+\to \mathbb R$ as above.

For every $y\in\mathbb R$ the function $g_y: [0,n]\to \mathbb R$ defined by
$$ g_y(x) = U(x) -xy $$ is continuous in the compact interval [0,n].

Therefore $g_y$ is bounded and attains its bounds and we may set
$$G(y) =  \sup_{x\in[0,n]}  g_y(x)$$
and define a function $F:\mathbb R\to [0,n]$ such that 
$$g_y(F(y)) =G(y).$$

That is $F(y)$ is the maximizer of $g_y$.

Therefore we have
$$E(\sup_{f\in B_n} U(f) - fh) \leq E(\sup_{x\in[0,n]} U(x) - xh) = E(G(h)).$$

It's easy to see from your conditions on $U$ that $F$ is continuous.

Thus the composition $X(\omega) = F(h(\omega))$ is measurable and we have $X\in B_n$.

So $$\sup_{f\in B_n}E( U(f) - fh) \geq E( U(X) - Xh) = E(g_h(X)) = E(G(h)).$$

Hence $$\sup_{f\in B_n}E( U(f) - fh) \geq E(\sup_{f\in B_n} U(f) - fh).$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have some questions: 1. why is $E[\sup_{f\in B_n} U(f)-fh]\le E(\sup_{x\in [0,n]}U(x)-xh)$?. 2. why is exactly is $F$ continuous?

Comment: @math: 1. For $f\in B_n$ and $\omega\in\Omega$ we have $f(\omega)\in[0,n]$ so $U(f(\omega)) - f(\omega)h(\omega) \leq \sup_{x\in[0,n]} U(x) - xh(\omega)$ for every $f\in B_n$ and every $\omega\in\Omega$.

Comment: 2.  $g_y'(x) = U'(x) - y$ is continuous and decreasing, so $g_y$ is maximized over $\mathbb R$ for the unique value of $x$ with $U'(x) = y$. This is continuous because $U'$ has a continuous inverse. Set $F(y) = x$ if $x\in[0,n]$, $F(y) = 0$ if $x<0$ and $F(y) = n$ if $x>n$.